# Android Retrofit + SimpleXmlConverter with Empty entity

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, simple-xml-converter

I'm trying to request Restful api data from retrofit, with SimpleXmlConverter.

But I got this error.

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Parameter     'comMsgHeader' does not have a match in class     tylenol.common.model.retrofit.routelist.ServiceResult
```

Sample XML Request

```
<ServiceResult>
<comMsgHeader/> <-- This tag make me annoying -->
<msgHeader>
    <headerCd>0</headerCd>
    <headerMsg>...</headerMsg>
    <itemCount>0</itemCount>
</msgHeader>
<msgBody>
    <itemList>
        ....
    </itemList>
</msgBody>
```

And this is my data class written by kotlin.

```
data class ServiceResult(
    val msgHeader: MsgHeader? = null,
    val msgBody: MsgBody? = null,
    val comMsgHeader: List<ComMsgHeader>? = null)
```

Sorry for bad english skills.

Comment: Have you tried using the `@Element` annotation?

Comment: Yes, I did. but not worked T^T